# Blazor WASM app "Cannot load file or assembly" for referenced project

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I have an ASP.NET hosted Blazor WASM app (.net 6) that references a .net 6 class library named `xxxxxx.Contracts` which is a library shared between the client and the server.

This has been working just find for some time, but suddenly when I try to run my app I get an exception as soon as any reference is made to any of the types within that class library.

Does anyone know why?

[image: Network and console windows]

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the solution didn't work, but deleting all the bin/obj folders then rebuilding the app did. I used the `cleanup` tool.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-cleanup/